# Criar uma coluna para cada linha retornada do Select

Tags: postgresql

Ontem postei uma pergunta referente a como retornar algo mesmo que não haja registros encontrados, e com o auxilio do @RovannLinhalis conseguimos chegar a seguinte `query`:

```
with dados as ( 
SELECT 
public.controleimpressoes.codigo, 
public.impressoras.patrimonio, 
public.impressoramodelo.modelo, 
public.impressoralocal.descricao, 
data, 
diferecacontador, 
diferecacontadordigital, 
diferencacontadorcolor, 
public.empresa.nome, 
datainicial, 
datafinal 
FROM 
public.controleimpressoes, public.impressoras, public.impressoramodelo, 
public.impressoralocal, public.empresa 
where 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoempresa = public.empresa.codigo and 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoimpressora = public.impressoras.codigo and 
public.impressoras.codigomodelo = public.impressoramodelo.codigo and 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoimpressoralocal = public.impressoralocal.codigo and 
data between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31' and 
public.impressoras.patrimonio between '1000' and '1882' and 
public.empresa.nome between 'A' and 'B' and 
public.impressoramodelo.modelo between 'C748' and 'C748' 
), meses as ( 

Select distinct 
intervalo, 
d.patrimonio, 
d.modelo, 
d.descricao, 
d.nome 
FROM generate_series('2017-01-01'::timestamp, '2017-12-31'::timestamp, '1 Month') as intervalo 
CROSS JOIN dados d) 


SELECT DISTINCT 
to_char(intervalo , 'TMMon') dataMes, 
m.*, 
(case when d.diferecacontador is null then 0 else d.diferecacontador end), 
d.diferecacontadordigital, 
d.diferencacontadorcolor, 
d.datainicial, 
d.datafinal 
FROM meses m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DADOS d on date_trunc('month',d.data) = m.intervalo and m.patrimonio = d.patrimonio 
order by m.nome, m.patrimonio, intervalo
```

Que me retornou os dados que eu precisava.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém como estou usando esse select para gerar um relatório no JasperStudio, minha necessidade seria transformar esse retorno para algo semelhante a isso:

```
Pat. | Mod  | Setor Inst.    | Empresa              | M1  |C1 | M2  |C2 | M3  |C3 | M4  |C4 | M5  |C5    | M6  |C6   | M7  |C7  | M8  |C8 | M9  |C9 | M10 |C10| M11 |C11| M12 |C12
1854 | C748 | 4º andar - 401 | A                    | Jan | 0 | Fev | 0 | Mar | 0 | Abr | 0 | Mai | 2409 | Jun | 551 | Jul | 39 | Ago | 0 | Set | 0 | Out | 0 | Nov | 0 | Dez | 0




select * from crosstab (
'with dados as ( 
SELECT 
public.impressoras.patrimonio, 
public.impressoramodelo.modelo, 
public.impressoralocal.descricao, 
data, 
diferecacontador, 
diferecacontadordigital, 
diferencacontadorcolor, 
public.empresa.nome, 
datainicial, 
datafinal 
FROM 
public.controleimpressoes, public.impressoras, public.impressoramodelo, 
public.impressoralocal, public.empresa 
where 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoempresa = public.empresa.codigo and 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoimpressora = public.impressoras.codigo and 
public.impressoras.codigomodelo = public.impressoramodelo.codigo and 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoimpressoralocal = public.impressoralocal.codigo and 
data between \'2017-01-01\' and \'2017-12-31\' and 
public.impressoras.patrimonio between \'1000\' and \'1882\' and 
public.empresa.nome between \'A\' and \'B\' and 
public.impressoramodelo.modelo between \'C748\' and \'C748\'
), meses as ( 

Select distinct 
intervalo, 
d.patrimonio, 
d.modelo, 
d.descricao, 
d.nome 
FROM generate_series(\'2017-01-01\'::timestamp, \'2017-12-31\'::timestamp, \'1 Month\') as intervalo 
CROSS JOIN dados d)


SELECT DISTINCT 
to_char(intervalo , \'TMMon\') dataMes, 
m.*, 
(case when d.diferecacontador is null then 0 else d.diferecacontador end), 
d.diferecacontadordigital, 
d.diferencacontadorcolor, 
d.datainicial, 
d.datafinal 
FROM meses m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DADOS d on date_trunc(\'month\',d.data) = m.intervalo and m.patrimonio = d.patrimonio 
order by m.nome, m.patrimonio, intervalo') as final_result (Pat text, Modelo text, Descricao text, datas timestamp, diferecacontador numeric, diferecacontadordigital numeric, diferencacontadorcolor numeric, empresa text, datainicial timestamp, datafinal timestamp)
```

Comment: Você quer transformar o resultado num [pivot table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table)?

Comment: sabendo a quantidade de colunas até que dá pra fazer rsrs complica quando a quantidade é dinâmica

Comment: @RovannLinhalis A quantidade de colunas seria sempre a mesma a principio

Comment: como @Laerte falou, você precisa do pivot table, dá uma olhada aí, quando eu liberar aqui...se nao tiver conseguido tento te ajudar

Comment: @RovannLinhalis obrigado, vou pesquisar referente a pivot table e ver se consigo implementar na minha necessidade

Comment: acho que é possível inclusive fazer isso na ferramenta de report... procura por cross tab nela tambem

Comment: @Laerte obrigado pela dica, vou pesquisar como utilizar o pivot table :)

Comment: @Laerte atualizei  minha pergunta como o modo como tentei realizar o `pivot table` mas deu um erro, sabe me dizer o que estaria errado?

Comment: você tem que fazer o crosstab no select inteiro... nao no primeiro apenas...rs

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74248/discussion-between-r-santos-and-rovann-linhalis).

Comment: @R.Santos infelizmente agora não vou conseguir lhe ajudar agora, mas o Rovann acredito que consiga lhe auxiliar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que seu resultado final seria esse:

```
select * from crosstab ( 
'with dados as ( 
SELECT 
public.impressoras.patrimonio, 
public.impressoramodelo.modelo, 
public.impressoralocal.descricao, 
data, 
diferecacontador, 
diferecacontadordigital, 
diferencacontadorcolor, 
public.empresa.nome, 
datainicial, 
datafinal 
FROM 
public.controleimpressoes, public.impressoras, public.impressoramodelo, 
public.impressoralocal, public.empresa 
where 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoempresa = public.empresa.codigo and 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoimpressora = public.impressoras.codigo and 
public.impressoras.codigomodelo = public.impressoramodelo.codigo and 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoimpressoralocal = public.impressoralocal.codigo and 
data between ''2017-01-01'' and ''2017-12-31'' and 
public.impressoras.patrimonio between ''1000'' and ''1882'' and 
public.empresa.nome between ''4All Tecnologia Ltda'' and ''4All Tecnologia Ltda'' and 
public.impressoramodelo.modelo between ''C748'' and ''C748'' 
), meses as ( 

Select distinct 
intervalo, 
d.patrimonio, 
d.modelo, 
d.descricao, 
d.nome 
FROM generate_series(''2017-01-01''::timestamp, ''2017-12-31''::timestamp, ''1 Month'') as intervalo 
CROSS JOIN dados d) 


SELECT DISTINCT 
m.patrimonio, 
to_char(intervalo , ''TMMon'') dataMes, 
coalesce(d.diferecacontador,0) as valor 
FROM meses m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DADOS d on date_trunc(''month'',d.data) = m.intervalo and m.patrimonio = d.patrimonio 
order by 1,2') 
as final_result (
patrimonio varchar,  
 "Jan" numeric, 
 "Fev" numeric, 
 "Mar" numeric, 
 "Abr" numeric, 
 "Mai" numeric ,
 "Jun" numeric, 
 "Jul" numeric, 
 "Ago" numeric, 
 "Set" numeric, 
 "Out" numeric, 
 "Nov" numeric, 
 "Dez" numeric);
```

Comment: Deu certo Rovann Muito obrigado pela ajuda, uma questão só, eu poderia adicionar mais itens nessa consulta como nome e modelo por exemplo?